# Update specific JSON file parameter after searching for it's value from other file through Python

Tags: python, json, search, replace

I'm trying to update a specific parameter of JSON file after referencing another data file (can be of any format text, ruleset etc) through Python.

The JSON file '**sample.json**' is:

```
{'Main': {'Attribute': {'Type': 'X::Y::Z', 'Dictionary': {'Object': {'Key1': false, 'Key2': false}}}}}
```

The content of data file (**requirements.ruleset** / **requirements.txt**) is:

```
X::Y::Z Dictionary == {"Key1": true, "Key2": true}
```

The python code that manually updates the value of `"Key1": true` & `"Key2": true`

```
import json

a_file = open("sample.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
a_file.close()
print(json_object)

#Manual way to update the value of Key1 & Key2 to be "true"
json_object["Main"]["Attribute"]["Dictionary"]["Object"]["Key1"] = "true"
json_object["Main"]["Attribute"]["Dictionary"]["Object"]["Key"] = "true"

a_file = open("sample_file.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, a_file)
print(json_object)
a_file.close()
```

It correctly updates the sample.json file with the value of `"Key1": true` & `"Key2": true` . Updated sample.json file

```
{'Main': {'Attribute': {'Type': 'X::Y::Z', 'Dictionary': {'Object': {'Key1': 'true', 'Key2': true}}}}}
```

How can I update the values of the Key1 & Key2 to "true" automatically by referencing **(requirements.ruleset / requirements.txt)**!
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. And there are some changes to be made in your txt and json files. Copy from the code I give.
**Code:- sample.json**

```json
{"Main": {"Attribute": {"Type": "X::Y::Z","Dictionary": {"Object": {"Dictionary": {"Key1": false,"Key2": false}}}}}}
```

**Code:- requirements.json** (Make is requirements.json instead of txt)

```
{"Dictionary" :{"Key1": true, "Key2": true}}
```

**Code:- name.py**

```py
import json

def write_json(new_data, filename='sample.json'):
    with open(filename,'r+') as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)
        content['Main']['Attribute']['Dictionary']['Object'] = abcd
        file_data.update(content)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file)

a_file = open("sample.json", "r+")
content = json.load(a_file)

f = open('requirements.json', 'r')
abcd = json.load(f)

write_json(abcd)
print('Done!')
```

It worked in my. It will defenitely work in yours ok!
Don't forget to convert the txt file to json. 
**Happy coding!**